# How to get PySerial to accept 921600 Baud rate

Tags: python, pyserial

We have a motor controller that implements a USB->Virtual COM port that has a fixed baud rate of 921600 (the manual even states that the baud rate cannot be changed).  I found that if I use a terminal program like Terminal, I can pass the custom baud rate of 921600 and communicate with the instrument with no issues.  We are using Windows 7 pro, 64-bit version.

However, when I tried to do this in PySerial (v.2.7) using Python 2.7.10 (32 bit) like this:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial("COM3",921600)
```

I always encounter error saying that parameter is incorrect.

> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 202, in _reconfigurePort
>       raise ValueError("Cannot configure port, some setting was wrong. Original message: %r" % ctypes.WinError())
>   ValueError: Cannot configure port, some setting was wrong. Original message: WindowsError(87, 'The parameter is incorrect.')

The valid Baudrates seem to be the one listed in serialwin32.py

```
BAUDRATES = (50, 75, 110, 134, 150, 200, 300, 600, 1200, 1800, 2400, 4800,
             9600, 19200, 38400, 57600, 115200)
```

When I use any of the baud rate from the list there I can open the serial port (but not necessary able to communicate with the instrument).

Just adding 921600 hundred to this list in serialwin32.py doesn't do anything.  I have searched several forums and websites and so far nobody seems to have an answer on how to set this higher baud rate in Windows.  The baudrate above 115200 used to be unreliable in older versions of Windows, but I assume that Windows 7 should be able to handle a much higher transfer rate now especially that many USB IC like FTDI and CH430 can handle a much higher baud rate than 115200.

Does anyone know a way to get pySerial to accept a higher baudrate than 115200 in Windows?

Comment: `I assume that Windows 7 should be able to handle a much higher transfer rate now` -- I think it's more likely that the spec for valid baud rates in Windows hasn't changed in years, given the dearth of potential and actual applications for RS232 ports running at the speeds you're proposing.

Comment: What brand is your motor controller?

Comment: Newport ESP301.  It has a USB to VCOM that's fixed at 921600.  It's weird that I can talk to it with Terminal program, but I can't get PySerial to take 921600 so I don't think it has anything to do with the hardware.  This is a direct USB-B on newport to USB-A on my laptop.  Windows detects it as a COM port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try 921600 and haven't any problem.

Your adapter not supported high speed rs232.

You need buy a CP21XX or equal converter.

Moxa or Lantronix is good brand(test & using).

Try on: win7x64,Python2.7x32

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because I tried PySerial on my Keyspan USA-19HS at 921600 baudrate and it connects with no issue.

This suggests that the Newport ESP301 USB to VCom actually doesn't run at the advertised 921600.  I was reading on a couple of places saying how USB to VCom often don't honor the baud rate and it could be completely different what the actual baud rate is.