# How to set COM Port baud rate to 921600 on Windows?

Tags: serial-port, windows-7-x64, pyserial, baud-rate

**Problem**: How to access a device whose baud rate is 921600 from Windows 7 PC.

I have an embedded device and I used to connect to this device through USB Serial Port at a baud rate of 115200.

Now, the embedded device's baud rate is changed to 921600.  I cannot communicate with this device.

I have a terminal program (Teraterm) in which I can set the baud rate to 921600.  But I am not able to communicate with the emb device as the maximum baud rate that can be set in Windows 7 device manager for this device is 128000.

I even tried with a Python script (changing baud rate 921600) which was working earlier (at baud rate 115200).  Now it's not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Baud Rate, redux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11475845/custom-baud-rate-redux) ?

Comment: Thanks Dan.  I think there is no solution provided in that post.  Or am I missing the solution?. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get PySerial to accept 921600 Baud rate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31420390/608639)